# How to find the preimage of the set of positive real numbers?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $P$ be the set of positive real numbers. Find $f^{-1}(P)$ for a) b) c)

a) $f(x)=\sin x$ $(-\infty < x < \infty)$

b) $f(x)=x^2$ $(-\infty < x <  \infty)$

c)$ f(x)= 0$ for $(x<0)$ and  $=1$ for $(x \ge 0)$

my answer:

a) $\pi /6$
b) no clue
c) no clue

help me please

Comment: Your title is misleading. These functions have no inverses since they are not bijective. You are probably searching for the preimage of set $P$ under $f$.

Comment: right. sorry about the misleading title

Comment: Repair your title. Are you searching for $f^{-1}(1)$ or $f^{-1}(P)$?

Comment: F^-1 (P). and i will do. thank you

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

$$f^{-1}(P)=\{x\mid f(x)\in P\}$$

So in this context you are (probably) looking for:$$\{x\in\mathbb R\mid f(x)>0\}$$

**edit**

Answer on case b).

Here $\{x\in\mathbb R\mid f(x)>0\}=\{x\in\mathbb R\mid x^2>0\}=\mathbb R-\{0\}$

Comment: could you show me how to do a and c too?

Comment: Yes: do them exactly like b). Sorry, but we are here to teach you math, but not to do your homework.

Comment: right right. this is our practice problems.

Comment: so for A) then x E R: sinx >0 =pi/2

Comment: sorry, but my dinner starts now. Succes. :)

Comment: nah you good man. have a good one. at least you dont lie tho